# Why is my Logistic Regression returning 100% accuracy?

Tags: logistic, python

I'm starting with the regression models in Python, so I used the Titanic dataset from Kaggle. Problem is after I fit the training datasets and ran predict(), the accuracy returned as 100%, and the scores are returning the same.

Therefore I know something is wrong.

**Preprocessing**

I imported the dataset, filled the missing values, created some rules for the values like below:

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

df = df.drop(['PassengerId','Ticket','Fare','Cabin','Name'], axis=1)
df['Age'] = df['Age'].fillna(value=29)
df['Embarked'] = df.fillna('C')

y = df['Survived']
X = df.drop(['Survived'],axis=1)

X.loc[X['SibSp'] >= 2, 'SibSp'] = 2
X.loc[X['Parch'] >= 3, 'Parch'] = 3
X.loc[X['Age'] < 15, 'Age'] = 0
X.loc[(X['Age'] >= 15) & (X['Age'] < 60), 'Age'] = 1
X.loc[X['Age'] >= 60, 'Age'] = 2

X = pd.get_dummies(X,columns=['Embarked'])
X = pd.get_dummies(X,columns=['Pclass'])
X = pd.get_dummies(X,columns=['Sex'])
```

Then I used train_test_split() to create the training and testing datasets:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state=84)
```

**Post-processing**

```
model = LogisticRegression().fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

accuracy = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
accuracy_percentage = 100 * accuracy
print(accuracy_percentage)

print(model.score(X_train,y_train))
print(model.score(X_test, y_pred))
```

Both scores returned 1.0, and the accuracy I ran also returned 100%.

I've compared to numerous tutorials on the internet I could find, so I'm really lost here. I have probably written wrong code somewhere, but I'm struggling to identify it. I checked other results on StackExchange but no good either.

Any help?

My datasets have the respective shape: X_train: (668,10), X_test: (223,10), y_test: (223,), y_train: (668,)

**Solution**

The problem was indeed with the code, specifically in this part:

```
df['Embarked'] = df.fillna('C')
```

What it should've been is:

```
df['Embarked'] = df['Embarked'].fillna('C')
```

The consequence was that my 'Embarked' columns became either 1s or 0s instead of the actual port of embark.

Comment: Do you have a RHS variable that is perfectly correlated with the dependent variable?

Comment: Yep, the "y" dataset is the dependent variable from the model. It's called "Survived", and it's a column with either 1 or 0, depending on whether the person died or not.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. Is one of your "x's" perfectly correlated with your "y"?

Comment: The problem lies in your dummy variables, which make your data perfectly correlated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embarked and Survived are perfectly correlated to be exact. Drop it.

To see this:

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

df = df.drop(['PassengerId','Ticket','Fare','Cabin','Name'], axis=1)
df['Age'] = df['Age'].fillna(value=29)
df['Embarked'] = df.fillna('C')

#y = df['Survived']
#X = df.drop(['Survived'],axis=1)
X = df.copy()

X.loc[X['SibSp'] >= 2, 'SibSp'] = 2
X.loc[X['Parch'] >= 3, 'Parch'] = 3
X.loc[X['Age'] < 15, 'Age'] = 0
X.loc[(X['Age'] >= 15) & (X['Age'] < 60), 'Age'] = 1
X.loc[X['Age'] >= 60, 'Age'] = 2

X = pd.get_dummies(X,columns=['Embarked'])
X = pd.get_dummies(X,columns=['Pclass'])
X = pd.get_dummies(X,columns=['Sex'])

print(X.corr())
```

Or another way to see this would be

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

df = df.drop(['PassengerId','Ticket','Fare','Cabin','Name'], axis=1)
df['Age'] = df['Age'].fillna(value=29)
df['Embarked'] = df.fillna('C')

df['S==E'] = df.Survived == df.Embarked 
print(df.loc[df['S==E'] == False])
```

Comment: You're right! I ran X.corr() and 'Survived' was perfectly correlated to 'Embarked_0'. I feel this shouldn't be happening, was it my code or just coincidence? I'll keep trying. Thanks you!